# Line continuations in APL

Tags: apl

Is there a line continuation character in APL, i.e., a character that indicates input is not yet complete and continues parsing the next line?

The reason I want it is to input an array in a format similar to its shape, e.g., instead of:

```apl
Forecast ← 4 6 ⍴ 150 200 100 80 80 80 300 330 360 400 500 520 100 250 350 380 400 450 50 120 220 300 320 350
```

I'd like to write (where `\` is the hypothetical continuation character):

```apl
Forecast ← 4 6 ⍴ \
150 200 100  80  80  80 \
300 330 360 400 500 520 \
100 250 350 380 400 450 \
 50 120 220 300 320 350
```

I'm using GNU APL, if it's important, and I'm an almost-complete novice, so apologies if I simply haven't seen it yet.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is nothing like a line continuation character in any modern version of APL that I know of.

But you have a point - visual fidelity in defining arrays is important, but it has never really been addressed at the language level.

I would probably have done

```
Forecast ← 4 6 ⍴ 150 200 100 80 80 80, 300 330 360 400 500 520, 100 250 350 380 400 450, 50 120 220 300 320 350
```

or

```
Forecast ← 0 ⍴ 0
Forecast ← Forecast, 150 200 100  80  80  80 
Forecast ← Forecast, 300 330 360 400 500 520 
Forecast ← Forecast, 100 250 350 380 400 450 
Forecast ← Forecast,  50 120 220 300 320 350
Forecast ← 4 6 ⍴ Forecast
```

when explicit formatting was necessary.

Years ago, some versions of APL allowed you to enter character strings with embedded carriage returns in functions by simply not entering the trailing quote until you were done.  This feature had a similar effect, but only for strings, and only on a single function line.  It was eventually removed from IBM APL and Sharp APL, probably many others.  It may have been confusing for users who got stuck in what appeared to be an input loop, or maybe the native del editor could not handle such lines afterwards.

Comment: NARS is modern and [has a line continuation character](http://wiki.nars2000.org/index.php/Function_Editing).

Answer (score 3):

With GNU APL (and maybe other versions), you can use the following syntax:

```
A ← ⊃⍎¨⎕INP 'END'
  1 0 0
  0 1 0
  0 0 1
 'END'
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Dyalog's MiServer uses a great command which enables the developer to include JS-Code that is needed as part of the page within the APL-Code through a function "ScriptFollows" which simply scans the lines following this statement and returns all text from the next segment of continously commented lines.
This idea could also be (ab-) used to help with your request:

```
∇ foo
⍝ required functions need to be in the WS or can be defined here:
 dtlb←{⍵{((∨\⍵)∧⌽∨\⌽⍵)/⍺}' '≠⍵}   ⍝ delete trailing blanks
 ScriptFollows←{{∊{'⍝'=⊃⍵:'' ⋄ ' ',dtlb ⍵}¨1↓¨⍵/⍨∧\'⍝'=⊃¨⍵}dtlb¨(1+2⊃⎕LC)↓⎕NR 2⊃⎕SI}
⍝ end of initialization...
⍝ and then could just write:

 arr←4 4⍴2⊃⎕VFI ScriptFollows ⍬
⍝ 1 2 3 4
⍝ 5 6 7 8
⍝ 9 10 11 12
⍝ 13 14 15 16
∇
```

Disadvantage: rho of array needs to be stated independtly of data, so when you need to edit data, you'll have to edit in two places. Other than that, I must say that I really fell in love with this `ScriptFollows`-Stuff ;-)

Comment: The story goes on ;-)   More here: http://www.dyalog.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=880